# How can I make an outbound rule specifically for ping.exe on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ping, cmd.exe

I have all outbound traffic on my Windows 7x64 system blocked. How can I specifically allow only ping.exe to be used in the command line (cmd.exe) without making a blanket exeption rule for all applications on icmpv4?

I haven't found a solution that only unblocks ping.exe (or cmd.exe) successfully so far.

Comment: What firewall are you using?

Comment: If it can be done with Windows Firewall, [this](http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php) should be able to help.

Comment: @Karan, that is great software, I use it on all my PC's

Comment: @Moab: Yeah, it's pretty nifty but I'm not an expert on it so can it do what the OP wants?

Comment: @Karan, It should, once installed you can add exceptions to the rules which includes adding exe files to access the network and choose your protocols. This program is nothing more than a nice skin for the windows advanced firewall already installed. They will probably need the paid version, worth every penny imho.

Comment: I am using the windows firewall. If the program you mentioned is only a "nice skin for the windows advanced firewall" then what I wanted should just as well be possible without it. I already made rules for "cmd.exe" and "ping.exe" but unfortunately it doesn't work. If this program does merely the same but  with a different gui I don't think it can help me solve my problem.

Comment: "If the program you mentioned is only a "nice skin for the windows advanced firewall" then what I wanted should just as well be possible without it." - Yes, that's what I said above, but the GUI might help accomplish it easily and then you can look into the changes it made.

Comment: @Moab: The registered version seems to only enable notifications and allow the creation of temporary rules, so do you think the latter will be required in this case?

Comment: @Karan, i use the registered version because it allows blocking outbound system files and services. They can try the free version and see if it works for their purpose.